# c#フォームアプリでTextBoxのnameを動的に指定したい

Tags: c#

よろしくお願いします。

c#とSQLiteでWindowsフォームアプリケーションを作成しています。
VisualStudio Community 2015, windows8.1を使用しています。

複数あるボタンのうち１つをクリックすると、対応するTextBoxに「○」を出力させるという動きをさせたいと思っています。

Button1をクリック → TextBox aaa,TextBox bbb に「○」が出力される
Button2をクリック → TextBox aaa,TextBox ccc に「○」が出力される

このようなイメージです。

ボタンをクリックした時に○が出力されるTextBoxのnameはDBに入っており、
select文で抽出する所までは出来ています。

```
using(SQLiteDaraReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
   while(reader.Read())
   {
      reader["TBox_name"].Text = "○";
   }
}
```

上記の形で試しましたが、失敗しました。

私がやりたい事が上記のコードで伝わっているでしょうか？

http://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1147000486
こちらが一番参考になりそうだと思ったのですが、
TextBoxの配列に直接書き込んでいるので私のやりたいこととは違いました。

http://oshiete.goo.ne.jp/qa/6273058.html
こちらも参考になるかと思いましたが、やはり直接書き込んでいます。

私もTxtBoxの配列にnameを入れてみようと思って試しましたが、

```
using(SQLiteDaraReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
   while(reader.Read())
   {
      TextBox[] wTextBox = { reader["TBox_name"] };
   }
}
```

objectやstringはTextBoxに変換できないとの事なので、困っています。

参考になるサイトや意見など何でも良いので情報が欲しいです。
よろしくお願いします。

Comment: Formの処理なのかSQLiteの処理なのか質問を切り分けてください

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
Formの処理だと思っています。
SQLiteを利用しているのは、「○」を出力するTextBoxのnameをDBから持ってきているというだけです。
やりたいことはあくまでもタイトルの通り、TextBoxのnameを動的に指定したいという事です。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Controls`プロパティのstringインデクサはあくまで`Controls`内しか検索しないため、フォーム直下に存在しない一般の場合では再帰的に処理を行う必要があります。

実装例を挙げると以下のようになります。`Find`は指定したコントロール(=`parent`)の子孫にある`Name`が`name`のコントロールを探すメソッドです。

```
private static Control Find(Control parent, string name)
{
    // まずparentの子コントロールでnameを検索します。
    var r = parent.Controls[name];

    // 子コントロールでnameが見つかった場合、該当コントロールを返します。
    if (r != null)
    {
        return r;
    }

    // parentの子コントロールでnameが見つからなかった場合、今度は子コントロールでFindを実行します。
    foreach (Control c in parent.Controls)
    {
        // TODO:必要ならcに対する条件を追加します。

        // 子コントロールcを起点にしてnameを検索します。
        r = Find(c, name);
        if (r != null)
        {
            // cの子孫にnameが見つかった場合、該当コントロールを返します。
            return r;
        }
    }

    // nameが見つからなかった場合、nullを返します。
    return null;
}
```

またリフレクションを用いてフィールドを探すこともできます。

```
typeof(Form1).GetField(textBox1.Name, System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic).GetValue(this)
```

Comment: すみません、確かにControlsでは不足していました。UserControlに纏められている場合など同名コントロールは複数存在し得るので単純に再帰検索すればいいというものでもないような？（もちろん適切なparentを指定すれば十分ですが…） それとリフレクションが使えるのはGenerateMember=Trueの場合に限定されますね。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
オブジェクト指向が理解出来ていないので回答の内容がとても難しく感じています。return r は、while文の中に返す物で、r にはnullでは無かったTextBoxのnameが入っているという事なのでしょうか？

Comment: @mahuyu `Find`はまず`parent`の直接の子コントロールから`name`を検索し、見つからなければ`parent`の孫コントロールから検索するという処理です。子コントロール`c`に対する`Find`が`null`以外を返した場合、`foreach`およびすべての`Find`メソッドは打ち切られ最初に見つかった値が返されます。このようにメソッド内で同じメソッドを呼び出すのは「再帰」と呼ばれる重要なテクニックですので詳しく調べられることをお勧めします。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
そしてコメントの追加ありがとうございます。
再帰についても調べておきたいと思います。
parent というのは親コントロールの Name で、string name の name とはtextBoxのNameプロパティで設定している値(私の場合は reader["TBox_name"] )という事で間違い無いでしょうか？

Comment: @mahuyu `parent`にはフォーム自身を渡しますので、結局`Find(this, (string)reader["TBox_name"])`となるはずです。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。
privateですと呼び出しが出来ないと思ったのでクラスを作成してpublicに変えてコメントを参考に試してみたら readerはコンテキストに存在しませんと出ました。privateのままで行ったらものすごい数のエラーが出てきました。使い方などを調べてみます。

Answer (score 0):

そもそも、DBから直接TextBoxを操作しようとしているのが間違っています。
ドメイン(データベースなどへの操作)とビュー(表示)は、分離すべきです。

代わりにINotifyPropertyChangedを実装したクラスを定義します。

```
class TextData : System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged {
     public string Text {
         get{
             return this._Text;
         }
         set {
            if( this._Text == value )
               return;
            this._Text = value;
            this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke( this , new PropertyChangedEventArgs( nameof(Text) ) );
         }
     }
     private string _Text;

     public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

ドメイン(今回の場合DB)からの入出力は、このTextDataクラスに対して行います。

**フォームの処理**

フォームでは、TextBoxにTextDataオブジェクトをデータバインディングします。

```
textbox1.DataBindings( nameof( TextBox.Text ) ,
   textdata1 , nameof(TextData.Text) , true , 
   DataSourceUpdateMode.Never );
```

textdata1は、TextDataクラスのオブジェクトです。
このようにすることで、textdata1オブジェクトのTextプロパティが変更されると、
textbox1(TextBox)のTextプロパティが更新されるようになります。

**データベースの処理**

データベースからは、TextBoxではなく、textdata1に対する操作に変更します。

```
using(SQLiteDaraReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())　{
    while(reader.Read()) {
      textdata1.Text = "○";
   }
}
```

上記の例では、直接 textdata1 と指定していますがDictionaryなどを用いて管理しても構いません。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
参考にさせて頂きます。

Answer (score -1):

[Controlsプロパテ](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/system.windows.forms.control.controls(v=vs.110).aspx)ィを使用することで動的にコントロールを選択することができます。

```
Controls["bbb"].Text = "○";
```

---

コメントに書かれたコードが無茶苦茶です。

```
string c = reader["koumoku_nm"].ToString();
if (c != null) {
    Controls["(reader['koumoku_nm'])"].Text = "○";
}
```

まず`null`かどうかを判定する前にToString()を呼び出してしまっていますので、「オブジェクト参照がオブジェクト インスタンスに設定されていません。」が発生する要因です。
また動的にコントロールを選択するのではなく **"(reader['koumoku_nm'])"** という名前のコントロールを探そうとしています。そんな名前は存在するはずがありません。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
                            string c = reader["koumoku_nm"].ToString();
                            if (c != null)
                            {
                                Controls["(reader['koumoku_nm'])"].Text = "○";
                            }と記述したら、「オブジェクト参照がオブジェクト インスタンスに設定されていません。」とエラーが発生しました。nullかどうかの判定のやり方が間違っているのでしょうか。もう少し調べていきたいと思います。

Comment: 回答の編集ありがとうございます。
ToString()の呼び出しで上記のエラーが出る理由はまだ分かっていませんが、 "(reader['koumoku_nm'])" の件は分かりました。ダブルクォーテーションで囲ってしまっていたので中が全て文字列として受け取られているという事ですね。